# Firestore Rule: Only strings in List

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How can I check if there are only strings in `request.resource.data.myArray`?

Loops and recursive calls are not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible today, unless you know the size of the array, and you write an expression to check the element at each index.  However, what you're asking is a reasonable thing to want to do, and you should [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) for it.  Bear in mind, though, that it's a long way off from happening.

The only way this would eventually work is if the rules language had a lambda type where you could pass a predicate function into a method that ensures it only returns true for every element in the list.  But that concept doesn't exist right now, so it would require a fair amount of effort to implement.

Comment: is this still not available?